# Array result store in firebase database and display in collection view

Tags: arrays, firebase-realtime-database, uicollectionview, swift4, collectionview

Is it be possible to store the array result (contain image URL and food name) into firebase database and then retrieve from firebase database and display in collection view?
If yes, how can achieve?

Since I can't display the image URL and food name in the collection view, I trying to use alternative solution to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this to insert data in firebase as per your requirement you need to make some changes. This is just a reference code.**

```
func temp() {
        var arrTemp : [[String : Any]] = [[String : Any]]()

        for index in 0...3 {
            print("index :: \(index)")
            let dictTemp = [ "foodName" : "Abcd","imgUrl" : "https://"] as [String : Any]
            arrTemp.append(dictTemp)
        }

        let dictDetails  = [
            "uniqueId" : UUID().uuidString,
            "arrList" : arrTemp] as [String : Any]

        print("dictDetails :: \(dictDetails)")

        self.insertDateInFirebase(dictDetails) { (success) in
            print(success)
        }
    }

    func insertDateInFirebase(_ dictRecipeInfo : [String : Any], completionHandler:@escaping DBcompletionHandler) {
        if let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser {

            Database.database().reference().child("TableName").child(currentUser.uid).child(dictRecipeInfo["uniqueId"] as! String).setValue(dictRecipeInfo) {
                (error:Error?, ref:DatabaseReference) in

                if let error = error {
                    print("Error :: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    completionHandler(false)
                }
                else {
                    completionHandler(true)
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            completionHandler(false)
        }
    }
```

**To retrieve data from firebase:**

```
func retrieveData() {
         if let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser {
             let dataBaseRefExeRoutine = Database.database().reference().child("TableName").child(currentUser.uid)

             dataBaseRefExeRoutine.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with:{ (snapshot) in

                 for snap in snapshot.children {
                     let objSnap = snap as! DataSnapshot

                    var arrMeals = [[String : Any]]()

                    //get meal item array (array with key 0,1 etc..)
                    if let arrMealItems1 = objSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "uniqueId").value as? NSArray {
                        for obj in arrMealItems1 {
                            if let dict = obj as? [String:Any] {
                                arrMeals.append(dict)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                 }
             }) { (error) in
                 print("Error :: \(error.localizedDescription)")
             }
         }
     }
```

Comment: Is it required use firebase storage to store the images?

Comment: yes first upload image in firebase storage and in success it will return one image URL, Store that URL in your main DB